# how to change Height of Calendar control in Xamarin form?

Tags: xamarin.forms, calendar

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          x:Class="LeaveManagerApp.UpcomingLeavesPage"
          xmlns:controls="clr-             namespace:XamForms.Controls;assembly=XamForms.Controls.Calendar"
        >
<Grid >
<controls:Calendar 
x:Name="MyLeaveCalendar"                       
ShowNumberOfWeek="false"
StartDay="Sunday" 
WeekdaysBackgroundColor="DarkBlue"
TitleLabelTextColor="DarkBlue"
SelectedDate="{Binding Date}"
SpecialDates="{Binding Attendances}"
DateCommand="{Binding DateChosen}" 
>
</controls:Calendar>
</Grid>
```

How to  fit calendar to screen size in xamarin form ,
i am using calendar control of xamarin form ,tried HeightRequest but its not working.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms does not have a built-in Calendar control, so I think you're using something else?

Comment: using XamForms.Controls.Calendar

Comment: That comes from here: https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar

Comment: yes ,but how to fit this calendar control to screen size.

Comment: It seems this control does not look at the height, it just renders each row at a fixed height. This issue somewhat describes it: https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar/issues/54 If you want to it be fullscreen, you will probably have to build something yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it works                                       
 calendar.OnEndRenderCalendar += (sender, e) =>
{
 (calendar.Content as StackLayout).Children.Last().HeightRequest = 500;
};

Comment: Upgraded to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a default Xamarin.Forms control, it originates from here: https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar

It looks like the control is rendered with a fixed height. Searching through the issues, I found this one: https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar/issues/54

You can influence the height of a row with this code:

```
yourCalendar.OnEndRenderCalendar += (sender, e) => 
{ 
    (calendar.Content as StackLayout).Children.Last().HeightRequest = 500;
};
```

The only thing you need to do is determine the right height, build something yourself for it or open an issue on the repo.

Answer (score -1):

You should post a full XAML code but as per Xamarin standard how to expand full view of child control. Check the below code.

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <controls:Calendar 
    x:Name="MyLeaveCalendar"                       
    ShowNumberOfWeek="false"
    StartDay="Sunday" 
    WeekdaysBackgroundColor="DarkBlue"
    TitleLabelTextColor="DarkBlue"
    SelectedDate="{Binding Date}"
    SpecialDates="{Binding Attendances}"
    DateCommand="{Binding DateChosen}" 
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
</controls:Calendar>
</Grid>
```

And also it's depend on Xamarin Layout which layout you are using for XAML design. And how to use XAML extensible language in Xamarin form Please check the link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/

Comment: Because your posted code is not full, please post the full code of XAML and UI screen shots.

Comment: Has nothing to do with full code or not in this case. The used control just doesn't take into account the `HeightRequest` at all